# Как удалить дубликаты в списке словарей опираясь на определённое поле?

Tags: python, django, словари

Имеется вот такой список со словарями внутри:

```
dialog_data = [
{
    # Первое добавленное поле, ничего не делаем.
    'from': '1',
    'to': '2',
    'msg': 'Тест 1',
},
{
    # Это дубль по полю from и по полю to! Его надо удалить!
    'from': '1',
    'to': '2',
    'msg': 'Тест 2',
},
{
    # Это дубль по полю to! Его тоже нужно удалить!
    'from': '2',
    'to': '1',
    'msg': 'Тест 3',
},
{
    # Здесь тоже имеется дубль. Но здесь to имеет другое значение. Поэтому словарь ниже не удаляем!
    'from': '1',
    'to': '3',
    'msg': 'Тест 4',
}]
```

Я пытаюсь привести его к такому виду:

```
dialog_data = [
{
    'from': '1',
    'to': '2',
    'msg': 'Тест 1',
},
{
    'from': '1',
    'to': '3',
    'msg': 'Тест 4',
}]
```

Суть в том, что я пишу систему личных сообщений на данный момент. Вытаскиваю данные вот так:

```
# Получаем список всех сообщений, где я могу быть как отправителем (если написал я), так и получателем (если сообщение написали мне)
dialog_data = self.model.objects.filter(Q(from=user_id) | Q(to=user_id)).order_by('-time')
```

Сейчас получается так, что у меня отображаются все мною отправленные сообщения и так же все отправленные мне. Ковыряюсь в этом уже пару суток и уже начинают сдавать нервы, поэтому и решил попросить помощи здесь.
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Если в качестве БД используется PostgreSQL, то вы можете вытаскивать из базы сразу без дубликатов:

```
self.model.objects.filter(...).distinct('to')
```

Если нет, придётся фильтровать в коде:

```
filtered = {i['to']: i for i in dialog_data if 'to' in i}.values()
```

Comment: Это не совсем то. Это фильрация по одному полю. То, что мне нужно делается вот здесь https://repl.it/repls/SuperbSplendidPercent
Что скажете по этому поводу? Возможно ли как-то упростить часть в normalize?

Comment: @Aquinary `distinct` и по нескольким полям работает.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

https://repl.it/repls/SuperbSplendidPercent

Не уверен, что это самое правильное решение, но оно работает.